# Почему у меня меню не работает на маленьких экранах

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

http://cw09756.tmweb.ru/app/

```js
var button = document.querySelector('i');
var list = document.querySelector('.menu-list');

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    list.classList.toggle('openMneu')
});
```

```css
.s-menu {
  background-color: #191d30;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#6081a0), color-stop(59%, #0e142d), to(#0e142d));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #6081a0 0%, #0e142d 59%, #0e142d 100%); }

.menu {
  padding: 36px 0; }

.menu-list {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 36px 0;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center; }
  .menu-list .menu__item {
    color: #fffbf4;
    font-family: "PT Sans";
    font-size: 27px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 31.61px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    position: relative; }
    .menu-list .menu__item > a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #fff; }
    .menu-list .menu__item:first-child {
      padding-left: 0; }

.menu__item:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 3px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 30px;
  left: 15px;
  top: 6px;
  background-color: #5b5a6e;
  z-index: 10; }

.menu__item:first-child:after {
  width: 0;
  height: 0; }

.hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  right: 100px;
  top: 23px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
  color: #fff; }

.a {
  width: 100%; }

.openMneu {
  display: none; }
```

```html
<section class="s-menu">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="menu">
     <ul class="menu-list">
      <li class="menu__item">
       <a href="#">Лекции</a>
       <!-- <span class="menu__item_span">|</span> -->
      </li>
      <li class="menu__item">
       <a href="#">Содержание</a>
       <!-- <span class="menu__item_span">|</span> -->
      </li>
      <li class="menu__item">
       <a href="#">Отзывы</a>
       <!-- <span class="menu__item_span">|</span> -->
      </li>
      <li class="menu__item">
       <a href="#">Контакты</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
     <button class='hamburger'><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></button>
    </div>       
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Что значит - не работает?

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko на больших экрнах hamburger работает, а на маленьких нет

Comment: Отлично, спасибо за ответ! *на больших экрнах hamburger работает, а на маленьких нет* - что значит работает?

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko открывается и закрывается при нажатии левой кнопкой мыши на дексктопе, а на мобиле нет

Comment: У меня на десктопе при нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит.